# mySQL Off business hours records

Tags: mysql

My system needs to respond to customers, based upon on or off business hours;

- 8:01 am to 8:00 pm (business hours)
- 8:01 pm to 8:00 am (off business hours)

I created the following table;

```
CREATE TABLE responses (
  response_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  start_at time DEFAULT NULL,
  end_at time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (response_id)
);
```

The business hour query work fine;

`SELECT * FROM responses WHERE CURTIME() BETWEEN start_at AND end_at;`

*Off Business Hours*: Notice start time is 8:01 pm while 8:00 am is end time. In this case, start time is smaller than end time, but hand in hand, it changes the day as well.

In this scenario, what is the best way to write the mySQL SELECT Query?

Comment: not sure what you mean? Efficient in what way? Why is the current scheme a problem for you? It's not clear what you're talking about with the end_at value? Maybe I have missed something obvious but the question isn't all that clear to me

Comment: Why just `SELECT * FROM responses WHERE off_hours=1/0` and handle the "is it on/off hours?" logic in the application?

Comment: @ceejayoz system might have more time periods for different type of response, that is why off_hours=1/0 wont work

Comment: @ADyson, question is how can we check time when the day is changed (ref: end_at when its 8:00am while start_at is 8:01 pm)

Answer (score 1):

Use NOW() and dateTime fields instead of CURTIME() and Time fields.

Right now you are comparing something like this:

```
WHERE '22:00:00' BETWEEN '20:00:01' AND '8:00:01'; // returns FALSE
```

But when you use dateTime across days it does something like this:

```
WHERE '2018-10-23 22:00:00'  BETWEEN '2018-10-23 20:00:01' AND '2018-10-24 8:00:01' // returns TRUE
```